# MongoDB create a filtered collection with 2 collections data

Tags: mongodb, filter, collections

I have a mongo database that consist of huge github data (users, issues, repos, etc).
I want to create small collections from this big data. 
I sorted "users" collection according to "followers" count of users. 
Then I got the first 1000 users from this query.

```
db.getCollection("users").find({}).sort({followers:-1}).limit(1000).forEach(function(doc){
db.usersnew.insert(doc);});
```

There is another collection called "repos" that consists of info about users' repository. (user key field :"owner.id" )

I want to create a new filtered repos collection which consists only users who present in usersnew collection.

I tried to use $look_up but it works like join.

```
db.getCollection('reposnew').aggregate([{
$lookup:
    {
        from: "users",
        localField: "owner:id",
        foreignField : "id",
        as: "filteredRepo"
    }
}])
```

It creates users collection + repos in a one collection.
I want only filtered repos collection with specific users' data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to add an [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage.

```
db.getCollection('reposnew').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "users",
            localField: "owner.id",
            foreignField : "id",
            as: "filteredRepo"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "filteredRepo.0": {$exists: true}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            filteredRepo: 0
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "newCollectionName"
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this but it produced nothing. The new collection is empty. The repos collection has got nested field. owner is a field type of user. Is "owner:id" syntax right, isn't it? I created a simple database with 2 collections to test this code.  with two "_id" field, it works. However, it didn't work with nested field  ("id <-> owner:id").

Comment: yea mb it was a typo, i fixed it.

Comment: Can i select only some fields from filteredRepo collection? I add to project,
$project: { field1 : 1, field2: 1} but it didnt work.